# Autoconf not linked in homebrew, how to link it?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to install autoconf view homebrew on mountain lion, I did this `$ brew install autoconf` and I got

`Warning: Could not link autoconf. Unlinking... Error: The brew link step did not complete successfully The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local You can try again using brew link autoconf ==> Summary /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69: 69 files, 2.0M, built in 52 seconds server:~ europemart$ brew link autoconf Linking /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69... Warning: Could not link autoconf. Unlinking... Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/ifnames Target /usr/local/bin/ifnames already exists. You may need to delete it. To force the link and delete this file, do: brew link --overwrite formula_name`

When I tried `$ brew install autoconf` again I get:

`Warning: autoconf-2.69 already installed, it's just not linked`

I've never used homebrew before and have barely any experience with terminal. Anyone able to help me out and get autoconf properly installed?

Cheers

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem before. As a result:

```
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autotest-mode.elc
```

Running with --dry-run:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
```

give info that:

```
    Would remove:
    ...
    /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/autoconf-mode.el
    ...
    /usr/local/share/autoconf/m4sugar/version.m4
    ... etc.
```

So I moved temporarly two folders `/usr/local/share/autoconf/` and `/usr/local/share/emacs/` (emacs folder - just in case) from it's default place away, and then run:

```
brew link --overwrite autoconf
```

And it works. Though, it's not an elegant way of doing it, Before I tried `brew doctor`, `brew update` and `brew tap homebrew/dupes` it didn't solve it. It seems that the problem came after unsuccessful `brew install` operation.

Answer (score 2):

Run with `$sudo`

```
$sudo brew link --overwrite --dry-run autoconf
```

OR

```
$sudo brew link --overwrite autoconf
```

Answer (score -3):

Like it says in the error message:

```
brew link --overwrite autoconf
```